# Spread operator vs JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) for immutable objects

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm working with Redux and recently ran into a problem where I was adding messages to an array and the Redux state was not issueing a re-render on React. I'm using the `react-redux` library for this. Here's an example of the problem I was having:

```
// State structure
structure: { messages: {}, groups: {} }

// ---
newState = { ...prevState };
newState.messages[action.message.group] = action.message;
return newState;
```

This was updating the state however it wasn't triggering an update to the react component, however replacing `newState = { ...prevState }` with `newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState))` resolved the issue.

Could anyone explain why this is happening in detail? I was under the impression that the spread operator created a clone of the object and I've never had any problems with it until now.

Comment: I think you should use this "Object.assign". without directly replace origin value, because we don't mutate the state in generally. (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)

Comment: The spread operator is only a shallow copy, not a deep copy like your serialize/deserialize approach. That could affect things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

react-redux connected components do a shallow strict equality check to decide if they want to update.  see http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html

The spread operator is like Object.assign and does not deeply clone an object.  The reason the JSON thing worked is because you created a whole new object which would pass the strict equality check, however all your components would update needlessly because nothing will pass a strict equality check now.

Object.assign({}, ...prevState, ...newState) would create a new top-level object, but it would not create a new object for any objects nested in prevState or newState. However, you would have to carefully update nested objects so as to avoid needless re-renders.  This can get tricky for deeply nested objects and arrays.

I'd recommend checking out the seamless-immutable or immutable packages for managing state.  Also, the reselect library can help you extract memoized objects specific to your component's needs.

## UPDATE 08/16/2020

the [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) library is one of the best state management libraries as of today

Comment: This is the only location where the problem occurs and it feels overkill to include a library on an application that we've been using redux in for several months. We were changing out data structures around while migrating to a MBaaS and ran into this problem, what do you feel would be the best course of action knowing that this is the only use-case? Do you feel that importing a library is necessary, or should serializing/deserializing work fine for this? I have a custom `componentShouldUpdate` that blocks unecessary renders based on a cache, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'd say if the app is working and you aren't currently having any performance problems a full re-render doesn't seem like a concern at the moment.  Switching to seamless-immutable later is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator is commonly used to make deep copies of JS objects. When we have nested arrays or nested data in an object, the spread operator makes a deep copy of top-level data and a shallow copy of the nested data. While JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) will do a deep copy of nested data also.